# Force figures and figures* to appear in order of appearance

Tags: floats, two-column, journal-publishing, journal, afterpage

I am using the [MNRAS latex template](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/) to typeset a preprint. The MNRAS template is divided into two columns and I am using the figure and figure* environment to place graphs either into one column or over the two columns.

However, the figures are put into the document in the order of appearance and figures* are *independently* put into the document in the order of appearance of figures*. As a result a "Figure 5" (a non* figure) appears in the document before "Figure 1" (a figure*).

How can I force the correct order of appearance of both figures and figures*?

---

Renumbering the figures is not an option as the journal requires the figures to appear in order of reference in text. I have tried using the afterpage package as a workaround so that Figures 1-4 are typesetted before Figure 5 but unfortunately \afterpage{\clearpage} triggers already after the left-column ending and the whole right column is left blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug (or rather, a documented limitation) in latex which was fixed if you loaded the `fixltx2e` package, and is fixed by default in LaTeX 2015/01/01.